# Vis.js: How to get a cluster node from the network

Tags: networking, cluster-analysis, vis.js

Is there a way to get the Node data for a cluster by its id?

According to the documentation:

> Clustered Nodes when created are not contained in the original data.nodes passed on network creation

So it's not possible to get it from the vis dataset like we do with normal nodes.

There is the method `network.clustering.updateClusteredNode()` to update a cluster node, but none to get the cluster node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this way (quite simple).
if the node id is 7 for example.
you can get its data like this.

```
network.body.nodes[7]
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: that's what we've ended up having to do in the end, though you have to do `network.body.nodes[id].options` to actually get the equivalent node data you would normally get from `nodes.get(id)`